# How to configure airflow master node

Tags: celery, airflow

I'm trying to modify an existing airflow-celery cluster to make the scheduler a dedicated master node that doesn't run jobs. (Currently, all of the nodes are functioning as workers; I want to prevent the scheduler from being a worker.)

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying with docker swarm with [this airflow distribution](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) You can specify in which kind of node to deploy each service.

So you can force to deploy scheduler in manager node:

```
scheduler:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
        placement:
            constraints: [node.role==manager]
```

And workers service in workers node:

```
worker:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    deploy:
        replicas: 3
        placement:
            constraints: [node.role==worker]
```

Answer (score 0):

In our cluster, the UI and the scheduler are on the same node. This is our “master” node.

When we start up these two components we use the commands:

```
airflow scheduler
airflow webserver
```

On the worker nodes, you start them with

```
airflow worker
```

This keeps your processes separate.

If you need additional help, please edit your answer and post your config file.